# Database is not created after publishing on Windows Azure

Tags: database, azure, publishing

Actually, I'm working on a basic ERP for a very small business. I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 Code First and I use Windows Azure as web hoster. All is working fine on my local computer, and deployement is done without issues : website is reachable. However, my application crash whenever a database access is required, with a "very descriptive" error : "Error. An error occurred while processing the request.". There are no clue or detailled error in logs file about this error.

After digging during two days, I've understood that my database is not initialized : all tables are created, but columns aren't set. Because tables are created, I doubt it's a connection string error, but a migrations one. All tries (though Initializer class) I have done to force a database reinitialisation failed.

I searched a while on the Internet, but I saw no one having the same issue than me.

Is trhere someone who have already encoutered this case, and is there a solution to fix it ? Thanks for your answers.

PS: Sorry for english mistakes, it's not my mothertongue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database you are using is `sql` than you should use 
[SQL Database Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) for deploying on-premises sql database to windows azure. This will do the job perfectly and effortlessly.

Comment: I just tried and it works perfectly ! Thanks ! I'm a bit disappointed MS did not add this kind of tool to publishing process. However, I still have the same error on my controller, but registration/login works now ! I will dig it more. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has a migration wizard built it. You can also export your database as a .bacpac file and upload it to Azure (but the SQL Migration Wizard is better IMHO)